# Update ASP.NET MVC Model value from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

In an ASP.NET MVC page, I'd like to change some valuee in the Model from javascript code when I click on an `onClick` button event.

I tried several solution but in any case the model is updated.

As exemple :
In the model there are :

- Firstname
- LastName
- Email.

In the razor page :

```
@Html.TextboxFor(model => model.LastName, new { id = "MyLastName" })
```

There is a button :

```
<button id="btnDelete" onclick="/*Code to update model*/ ">Click me</button>
```

In "Code to update model", I'd like change the model value for `@Model.FirstName` and `@Model.Email` via javascript.

I tried to assign `Model.LastName` to an `HiddenFor` :

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Lastname, new { id = "MyLastName" })
```

Get the value by javascript and change the value but the value in the Model is not updated.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: The model should be updated when you post it back. Do you have this field inside a form tag?

Comment: @Steve no there is no form tag.

Comment: Sorry but at this point I am very confused. If you don't post back the model with a submit button inside a form helper how do you check the values on the model? Probably you need to post the code of your page with the javasript code that you use to change the values.

Comment: @Steve It's an old application, made by a beginner 8 years back. Trust me you are not the only one to be confused ;-)

Comment: The .net "Model" (viewmodel) is *only* used to *build/render* the HTML.  After the HTML has been rendered and sent to the client, there is no Model.   You need to update the HTML elements, eg update the hidden input:  `$("#MyLastName").val(newvalue)`